# Change td background when radio button is checked

Tags: button, radio-button, html-table

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/greedylan/2tytxhoj/1/
```

So I need to have the background of TD cell turn into blue when my radio button is checked. These 7 buttons/labels would be taken out when necessary. I can not set positioning as fix (relative or absolute for each).

I found this:

```
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
   background:#293486;
}
```

But it only works with the label. I need the whole cell to be highlighted. Do we need Javascript for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need JS. 
You just have to adjust the size and position of the label and it will work:

```
td {
    position: relative
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    color: white;
    background-color:blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;    
}
```

You can then use padding to adjust the location of the text.

Comment: I can not set label's positioning for relative or absolute. because these 7 buttons and label would be taken out when necessary. That is why I set the background color inside the TD cell.

Comment: What do you mean they'll be taken out when necessary? Why can't you use absolute positioning - are you doing html emails?

Comment: you could try adding a div to the <td> to get the styling you want. If this doesn't work i'm at a loss as to what you want - why not just copy the source code from the link - they make it easily available.

Comment: I just tried what you suggested and it actually works. Could you explain why we put relative for TD and absolute for input radio? (im even more confused for  top: 0; left: 0;bottom: 0; right: 0; part)

Comment: 1. Relative on the TD sets up the boundaries for the absolute positioned element.2. setting t,b,l,r to 0 stretches the element to the edges, filling up all the space. it's like width 100% and height 100%. you then use padding to move the text where you want it to be within the td. does that make sense now?

Comment: Yes thank you very much, I am trying a few more things here to make the whole project work. Really appreciate your explanation.